# Retrieve Exchange Calendar event with Python & Suds

Tags: python, exchangewebservices, suds

I'm trying to retrieve Exchange calendar events in Python using the suds library.

I'm able to read FreeBusyResponse data, but I'm not successfull in retrieving the actual calendar event.

The soap requests seems fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"     
xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"     
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     
xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" 
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
      <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010_SP1"/>
   </SOAP-ENV:Header>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:FindItem Traversal="Shallow">
         <ns1:ItemShape>
            <ns0:BaseShape>Default</ns0:BaseShape>
         </ns1:ItemShape>
         <ns1:CalendarView xsi:type="ns0:CalendarViewType" StartDate="2016-10-17T14:10:41.620151+01:00" EndDate="2016-10-17T14:10:41.620176+01:00"/>
         <ns1:ParentFolderIds>
            <ns0:DistinguishedFolderId xsi:type="ns0:DistinguishedFolderIdType" Id="calendar">
               <ns0:Mailbox>
                  <ns0:EmailAddress>dries@myhost.be</ns0:EmailAddress>
               </ns0:Mailbox>
            </ns0:DistinguishedFolderId>
         </ns1:ParentFolderIds>
      </ns1:FindItem>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Relvant part in the code:

```
find_item_request = client.factory.create('FindItemType')
shape_types = client.factory.create('ns1:DefaultShapeNamesType')
shape_type = client.factory.create('ns1:ItemResponseShapeType')
shape_type.BaseShape = 'Default'
find_item_request.ItemShape = shape_type
find_item_request._Traversal = 'Shallow'

mailbox = Element('ns1:Mailbox')
emailaddress = Element('ns1:EmailAddress').setText('dries@myhost.be')
mailbox.append(emailaddress)

folder_id_type = client.factory.create('ns1:DistinguishedFolderId')
folder_id_type.Mailbox = mailbox
folder_id_type._Id = 'calendar'

folder_ids = client.factory.create('ns1:NonEmptyArrayOfBaseFolderIdsType')
folder_ids.DistinguishedFolderId = folder_id_type
find_item_request.ParentFolderIds = folder_ids

calendar_view = client.factory.create('ns1:CalendarViewType')
calendar_view._StartDate = start
calendar_view._EndDate = end
find_item_request.CalendarView = calendar_view

client.service.FindItem.method.soap.input.body.wrapped = False

try:
  find_item_response = client.service.FindItem(find_item_request)
except WebFault as e:
  raise e
msg = result.FindItemResponseMessage
```

Should I use something else than a CalendarView?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the following solution:

```
import time
import datetime
import pytz
from suds.client import WebFault
from suds.client import Client
from suds.sax.element import Element
from suds.transport.http import HttpTransport
from suds.sudsobject import asdict

< auth and transport comes here >

# Todo: fix timezones displayed in suds output.
start = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Europe/Brussels')).isoformat()
end = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Europe/Brussels')).isoformat()

fi = client.factory.create('FindItem')
fi.ItemShape.BaseShape = 'AllProperties'
fi.ParentFolderIds.DistinguishedFolderId = client.factory.create('t:DistinguishedFolderIdType')
fi.ParentFolderIds.DistinguishedFolderId._Id = 'calendar'
fi._Traversal = 'Shallow'

calendar_view = client.factory.create('CalendarView')
calendar_view._StartDate = start
calendar_view._EndDate = end
fi.CalendarView = calendar_view

#client.service.FindItem.method.soap.input.body.wrapped = False

try:
  response = client.service.FindItem(**asdict(fi))
  print response
except WebFault as e:
  raise e
```